# Изменить время текущей даты до 23:59:59

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, timezone

У каждого объекта Task есть срок годности и мне нужно сделать выборку от текущего времени и даты до той же даты, но время должно быть эквивалентно "23:59:59".

```
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(project__user=request.user, #  for a day
                                date_until__gte=timezone.now(),
                                date_until__lt=timezone.now()+timezone.timedelta(days=1),
                                status='')
```

Т.е. нужно изменить аргумент date_until_lt, который на данный момент делает выборку ровно на сутки вперед. Спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос был решен с помощью инфы по данной ссылке
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468823/python-datetime-setting-fixed-hour-and-minute-after-using-strptime-to-get-day

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime

dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time.max)
print(dt.isoformat())  # 2019-06-26T23:59:59.999999
```

Т.е. в вашем случае, приходит какой-то `datetime`, и вместо сегодняшнего числа `date.today()`, вы забираете пришедший день `datetime.date()`.